# Match combination of split amounts from a list to an specified amount

Tags: c#, sql

I've created an automation to match payments detailed in a csv file with what is stored in a database.

The report amount and the DB amount may not always be a one to one relationship (There is no key value to match upon (It is a composite key, CustNum, PaymentType, PaymentDate, PaymentTime) - The only info I have from the csv file is CustNum, PaymentType, PaymentDate and Amount). The DB and Report are fixed and cannot be changed.

The csv file comes from a Web service call to a windows based system and the DB information stores information which has been extracted from a Mainframe.

The CSV reports payments which the windows based system has not received an acknowledgement for the payment processing. There could be a number of reasons why the acknowledgement has not been received as there are a multitude of in-between systems each with their own idiosyncrasies.

Example Report:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      CustNum        |   PaymentType    |   PaymentDate    |      Amount      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        001          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      500.00      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        002          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      2005.23     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        003          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      387.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Example DB Rows:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      CustNum        |   PaymentType    |   PaymentDate    |      Amount      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        001          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      500.00      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        002          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      2000.00     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        002          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |       5.23       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        003          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      387.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        003          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      147.51      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I initially sum the Amount field for all records for the given, CustNum, RecordType, PaymentDate and compare this to the reported Amount on the csv.  If this does not give a match I then try to match the individual payment amounts instead of summing them.  This method was more efficient as there seems to be more split payments than straight one to one relationship payments. A split payment is where the Database holds multiple records for one payment, but when summed give the reported Amount.

This works for the majority of cases like in the example above - However one case it does not work for is if there are multiple split payments in the DB for the given CustNum, RecordType and Payment date.

Example Report:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      CustNum        |   PaymentType    |   PaymentDate    |      Amount      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        001          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      500.00      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        002          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      2005.23     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        003          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      387.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Example DB Rows:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      CustNum        |   PaymentType    |   PaymentDate    |      Amount      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        001          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      500.00      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        002          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      2000.00     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        002          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |       5.23       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        002          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      10870.00    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        002          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |       549.84     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        003          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      387.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        003          |    Electronic    |    2020-04-01    |      147.51      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

In the above example the reported amount for CustNum 002 of 2005.23 will not be reported as matching as it is neither a single payment nor a sum of all the payments from that PaymentDate for the specified CustNum and PaymentType.

What I think I need to do is look for all the Amount combinations from the DB and compare these combinations to the reported value to determine if any of the values matches. But if someone has a better solution i'm open to changing it.

The above is a simplified example - the DB may have 10 or 20 split payment per CustNum matching the PaymentType on the specified PaymentDate.

I'm not sure what the best way to go about trying to match these, given the limited information I have and the way the report reports the payments.

Any guidance you could give on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you gave enough detail - where does the CSV file come from? Why would it only contain some of the transactions (split payment) for the same date?

Comment: I'll update the question with the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a brute force method, you can compute all combinations of the Amounts from the database and find if any match the CSV file Amount. Assuming once filtered by the other fields the number of Amounts is small, this should not be too slow:

Using these extension methods:

```
public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) => !src.Any();

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> start) {
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> HelperCombinations(IEnumerable<T> items) {
        if (items.IsEmpty())
            yield return items;
        else {
            var head = items.First();
            var tail = items.Skip(1);
            foreach (var sequence in HelperCombinations(tail)) {
                yield return sequence; // Without first
                yield return sequence.Prepend(head);
            }
        }
    }

    return HelperCombinations(start).Skip(1);
}
```

Assume that `amounts` is the collection of payments from the database, then:

```
var amounts = new[] { 2000.00, 5.23, 10870.0, 549.84 }.ToList();

var payment = 2005.23;

var ans = amounts.AllCombinations().Where(c => c.Sum() == payment).ToList();
if (!ans.Any()) { // no match
}
else if (ans.Count == 1) { // found payments that sum to match
}
else { // more than one possibility
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'll have a go with this. The most I've seen so far is about 20 split payments per custNum for a paymentType on a give paymentDate and this is rare normally it is only 4 to 6 for these scenarios. If I understand this correctly this will also work if the database only has one record. So I could replace the first two checks and just do this check.

Comment: @gheff Yes, this will work if only one database record is in `amounts`.

Comment: that worked awesomely. Only 2 changes I needed to make. I'm using .Net 4.5.2 so I needed to write my own Prepend method and the second was to not skip the first record in the initial HelperCombinations call, as the headers weren't being returned in the DB call. My mistake for including it in the example.

Comment: Sorry an additional edit because I'm using .net 4.5.2 and visual studio 2017 was to un-nest the HelperCombinations method. Visual studio didn't like it. I think that feature was introduced in a later version

Comment: @gheff The `Skip(1)` in the `return` is to skip the empty `IEnumerable` that is the first return from the recursive method.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up and helping my understanding