# Matching List with List

Tags: c#

So I have a list of invoice and transaction. I need to do matching of invoices based on those both payments. Let's say

```
            List<int> invoices = new List<int> { 40, 30, 10, 20, 60, 4, 6 };
            List<int> payments = new List<int> { 80, 90 };
```

I want to find possible combination that will exactly match the first payments (80) and then based on the invoices that are left I want It to do matching with the second payment (90).

So the first section in the invoice list which are 40,30 and 10 should be match with first item in payment list(80) and 20, 60, 4 and 6 should match with second item in the payment list(90).

I only able to do matching with only 1 payment using recursive.

Comment: What if there are multiple ways to combine the numbers to get the first payment, but only one or a few of the combinations leave numbers that can be combined for the second payment?

Comment: It sounds like you want some form of the change making problemL https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: I was thinking of taking only the perfect combination. Since there will be multiple combinations, the only perfect combination for both matching will be selected.

Comment: But in your example there are several 'perfect' combinations: {60,20} {40,30,10,4,6} | {40,10,20,4,6} {30,60} and so on. Should it return the first valid combination?

Comment: Yes, first perfect combination should be sufficient

Comment: It's not clear what you define as 'perfect'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match combination of split amounts from a list to an specified amount](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61128194/2557128)

Comment: Why aren't you responding to the code I wrote for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a magic method. It runs through all possible variants and returns the first suitable combination of indices or null. Also it takes an array of indices that'll be excluded from the search; you can easily feed it with the result you got from the previous search.

---

```
static int[] Match(List<int> invoices, int payment, int[] exclude = default)
        {
            if (exclude == default) exclude = new int[0];
            List<int> selected = new List<int>();
            sbyte Add(int number)
            {
                int result = selected.Sum(index => invoices[index]) + number;
                if (result < payment) return -1;
                if (result > payment) return 1;
                return 0;
            }
            bool Continue(int start)
            {
                for (var i = start; i < invoices.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (exclude.Contains(i)) continue;
                    switch (Add(invoices[i]))
                    {
                        case 1:
                            break;
                        case -1:
                            selected.Add(i);
                            if (Continue(i + 1))
                                return true;
                            selected.Remove(i);
                            break;
                        case 0:
                            selected.Add(i);
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < invoices.Count; i++)
            {
                if (exclude.Contains(i) || invoices[i] > payment) continue;
                if (invoices[i] == payment) return new int[] { i };
                selected.Add(i);
                if (Continue(i + 1)) return selected.ToArray();
                selected.Remove(i);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

---

**The code in action** [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5aimI).

---

### Be careful.

Because there's so many combinations, it takes some time to process them all (especially big arrays).
Maybe you should consider something else.